# only one if statement is not working all of sudden. Please take a look

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

I am writing a code that executes commands that were inputted by users. Among the codes, my 1st elif statement is not working. It is supposed to open a file dialog so that the user can browse through files to get the one that is needed. It worked just fine like a moment ago and but when I ran it after deleting some lines and making some changes to the names of the functions (to make the code look better), it does not work all of a sudden. It opens filedialog, yes, but it does not import the file selected to the python any more. What may be the cause of this? The code looks like below:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter.filedialog

    def Assign():
        # do work
        return audit_assignment()

    def audit_assignment():
        while True:
            command = input('Enter command here: ')
            if command not in {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7"}:
                print('That is not a valid entry. Please enter a integer value from one through 
    seven.')
            
            elif command == "1":
                Mydf=pd.read_csv(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r'))
                print('File successfully opened')
Assign()
```

of course this code goes until `elif command == "7":` but I think the rest is not necessary here.

I also just figured out that when I stop debugging, the selected file comes into the python,  to Mydf, immediately.

Comment: You have shown us the code you say is working: *it opens the filedialog*. But if you want help we need to see the code that isn't working.

Comment: @BoarGules this code that is written in the post is NOT working. It works fine if executed just itself (Mydf=pd.read_csv(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r')))not the whole, though.

Comment: @BoarGules the code above opens the file dialog yes. but the file selected does not get imported to the variable Mydf.

Comment: How do you know? Neither of your code snippets does any thing with Mydf.

Comment: @quamrana I don't get what you mean. The line "Mydf=pd.read_csv(tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile(mode='r'))" is supposed to open a file dialog and save the datasets in the selected file to a variable named Mydf.

Comment: What I’m saying is that it looks like you are throwing away Mydf . If you were to do further processing on Mydf, then you would have some symptoms that you could report.

Comment: Does `audit_assignment` ever *return* a value? Please provide a [mcve].